# C# DataGridView Header

Tags: c#, datagridview

Firstly I'm quite new with programming(first week). I have a datagridviewer and CellClick event on it. What my function do is, gets the first column value of selected(mouse left clicked) cell of row.
Like;

ID Name Address    ( this ones Headers of gridview)

1 User1  Address1

2 User2  Address2

..6,7..

9 User9  Address9

When you click on any cell -except Headers- it gives the value of first column. When you click, Address9 your value will return as 9 etc.

I get outofexception error when header cell is clicked. Which returns -1 value and crashs.So, I need a if statement to ignore header clicks. I searched it on websites and tried many things myself but haven't managed to achieve this.

```
private void dgwCust_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)       
{            

if ( cellclick == isn't a header click?.. ) 

            string search;
            search = dgwCust.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();//this is where error comes in
            SqlCommand cmdsearch = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customers where CustomerID = '" + search + "'", dbConnection);
            try
            {
```

etc..

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: WinForms, but problem is already solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if e.RowIndex does not equal -1 by using one of the following

```
if (!e.RowIndex.Equals(-1))
```

or

```
if (e.RowIndex != -1)
```

-

```
private void dgwCust_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)       
{            

    if (!e.RowIndex.Equals(-1)) 

        string search;
        search = dgwCust.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();//this is where error comes in
        SqlCommand cmdsearch = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customers where CustomerID = '" + search + "'", dbConnection);
        try
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{
  string search;
  search = dgwCust.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();//this is where error comes in
  SqlCommand cmdsearch = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customers where CustomerID = '" + search + "'", dbConnection);
  //...
}
```